# using OOP approach to create plugin but stuck at making hyperlinks to work

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress development so please be patient if my question sounds simple or ridiculous, since I have been doing object oriented programming in PHP so i wanted to use the OOP approach in wordpress plugin development as well and came across [Boilerplate](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate). I have gone through the code in detail but I am still confused.

At present it comes with a view of `admin.php`, i wanted to create another page for testing purpose so i created a file view/`admin2.php`, I then want to create a hyperlink in `admin.php` to redirect the user to `admin2.php`, how can i do it? if i simply do the following, it does not work and gives me 404 error

```
<a href="admin2.php">go to admin 2</a>
```

I know i can create a sub menu but i do not want to do that yet. I will really appreciate any help here.

**UPDATE**

This is what my `admin.php` looks like

```
<?php
echo '<a href="'. plugins_url( 'admin2.php' , __FILE__ ) .'">Go to admin 2 page</a>';
?>
```

This is what my `admin2.php` looks like

```
<?php
echo '<a href="'. plugins_url( 'admin.php' , __FILE__ ) .'">Go to admin page</a>';
?>
```

Comment: What is the full path when you are viewing admin.php, and what is the full path when you get the 404?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

Comment: Developing for Wordpress is not typical MVC programming. Read [this article about creating admin pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus). If you want to use a separate page outside of the Wordpress framework, you'll need to [register rewrite rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) to tell Wordpress about your new, external view.

Answer (score 2):

The Wordpress has a handy function, called `plugins_url()`. It retrieves the **absolute URL to the plugins directory** (*without the trailing slash*) or, when using the `$path` argument, to a specific file under that directory. You can either specify the `$path` argument as a hard-coded path relative to the plugins directory, or conveniently pass `__FILE__` as the second argument (as you did) to make the `$path` relative to the parent directory of the current PHP script file:

`<?php plugins_url( $path, $plugin ); ?>`

However, if you are using the `plugins_url()` function **in a file that is nested inside a subdirectory of your plugin directory**, you **should** use PHP's `dirname()` function:

`<?php
  echo 
  '<a href="' . plugins_url( 'subfolder/admin2.php' , dirname(__FILE__) ) . '" > Go to admin 2 page </a> ';
?>`

Also the `plugins_url()` function should **not be called in the global context** of plugins, but rather **in a hook** like `init` or `admin_init` to ensure that the `plugins_url` filters are already hooked at the time the function is called. This is vital for many site configurations to work, and if `plugins_url()` is called in the global context of a plugin file **it cannot be filtered by other plugins** (though `mu-plugins` are able to filter it because they run before any other plugins).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're adding your plugin pages as subpages of an existing default item <sup>1</sup>, all our plugin pages are attached to `admin.php`. **There's no** `admin2.php`, **nor** `plugins_url()` will provide an actual URL for our admin page: *`http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=PLUGIN-PAGE`*.

<sup>**1** `add_management_page`, `add_options_page`, `add_theme_page`, etc.</sup>

The function `plugins_url()` provides access to our assets in the URL *`http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/our-plugin/`*. And what you're looking for is [**`admin_url( $path )`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url).

Here's a simple demonstration. Main plugin file:

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: (SO) OOP admin navigation
 * Plugin URI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23703521/1287812
 */

/**
 * Based on Plugin Class Demo
 * https://gist.github.com/toscho/3804204
 */
add_action(
    'plugins_loaded', 
    array( B5F_Demo_OOP::get_instance(), 'plugin_setup' )
);

class B5F_Demo_OOP
{
    protected static $instance = NULL;
    public $plugin_url = '';
    public $plugin_path = '';

    public function __construct() {}

    public function plugin_setup()
    {
        $this->plugin_url    = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
        $this->plugin_path   = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'menu' ) );
    }

    public static function get_instance()
    {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function menu()
    {
        add_menu_page( 
            'Main', 
            'Main Page', 
            'add_users', 
            'my-main-page', # <-- menu_slug used as URL param value
            function(){ 
                include_once( 'views/admin_menu.php' );
            },
            'http://s.w.org/favicon.ico'
        );  
        $hook = add_submenu_page(
            null,
            'Hidden',
            'Hidden Page',
            'add_users',
            'my-hidden-page', # <-- submenu_slug used as URL param value
            function(){ 
                include_once( 'views/admin_submenu.php' );
            }
        );
        # Print scripts
        // add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$hook", array( $this, 'enqueue' ) );
    }
}
```

**/views/admin_menu.php**

```
<?php   
printf(
    '<h2>%s</h2><a href="%s">%s</a>',
    __( 'Main page' ),
    admin_url( 'admin.php?page=my-hidden-page'), # http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-hidden-page
    __( 'Hidden sub page' )
);
```

**/views/admin_submenu.php**

```
<?php
printf(
    '<h2>%s</h2><a href="%s">%s</a>',
    __( 'Hidden sub page' ),
    admin_url( 'admin.php?page=my-main-page' ), # http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-main-page
    __( 'Main page' )
);
```